# Trying to make a custom RuntimeException class

Tags: java, exception

Ok so for school I have to currently make a program that can handle Rational number arithmetic. I have this part of my code completely done but a secondary part of the assignment is to create two custom exception classes. The first exception class was easy to create and was just a null object handling class. But the class I can't figure out is the custom divide by zero class. The problem is that we have specific parameters for the class which are:

```
Class - DivideByZeroException
Constructors - DivideByZeroException(), DivideByZeroException (Rational rational)
Instance Fields - Rational rational 
Public Methods - Rational getRational() - String getMessage() : override
```

The issue I'm having is that I don't have a any idea why it's necessary to Override getMessage when the class must extend RunTimeException thus enabling the super(message) call. Here is the source code for the class which can throw the exceptions and the class that should handle them. I may have some weird code I'm currently trying so if something doesn't make sense it was probably me getting frustrated.

```
package com.math.rational;

public class DivideByZeroException extends RuntimeException
{
    private Rational rational;

    DivideByZeroException()
    {
        super();
    }

    DivideByZeroException(Rational rational)
    {
        super();
        this.rational = rational;
    }

    public Rational getRational()
    {
        try
        {
        return this.rational;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("You have no rational object to retrieve");
            System.exit(1);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage()
    {
        if(this.rational != null)
        {
            return this.rational.toString();
        }
        else
        {
            return new String("You attempted to divide by zero");
        }
    }
}


package com.math.rational;

public class Rational
{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Rational(int numerator, int denominator)
    {

        try
        {
            this.numerator = numerator;
            this.denominator = denominator;

            int[] intHolder = simplify(this.numerator, this.denominator);
            this.numerator = intHolder[0];
            this.denominator = intHolder[1];

            if ( this.denominator == 0 || denominator == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("true");
                throw new DivideByZeroException(new Rational(this.numerator, this.denominator));
            }   
        }

        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }   
    }

    public Rational(Rational numerator, Rational denominator)
    {
        try
        {
        numerator.multiply(denominator.reciprocalNumber());

        if ( numerator.denominator == 0 || denominator.denominator == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("true");
            throw new DivideByZeroException(new Rational(this.numerator, this.denominator));
        }
        }
        catch(DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public int[] simplify(int tempNumerator, int tempDenominator)
    {
        int reduce = greatestCommon(getAbs(tempNumerator), tempDenominator);

        tempNumerator /= reduce;
        tempDenominator /= reduce;
        int[] size = {tempNumerator, tempDenominator};

        for(int i : size)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s ", i);
        }
        return size;
    }

    public int greatestCommon(int first, int second)
    {
        while(first != second)
        {
            if(first > second)
            {
                first -= second;
            }
            else
            {
                second -= first;
            }
        }

        return first;
    }

    public Rational reciprocalNumber()
    {
        return new Rational(this.denominator, this.numerator);
    }

    public int getAbs(int value)
    {
        return  Math.abs(value);
    }

    public Rational add(Rational other)
    {

        if(other.getDenominator() != this.getDenominator())
        {
            int commonDenom = this.getDenominator() * other.getDenominator();
            int firstNumerator = numerator * other.getDenominator();
            int secondNumerator = other.getNumerator() * this.getDenominator();
            int finalNumerator = firstNumerator + secondNumerator;
            return new Rational(finalNumerator, commonDenom);
        }
        else if(other.getDenominator() == this.getDenominator())
        {
            int finalNumerator = this.getNumerator() + other.getNumerator();
            return new Rational(finalNumerator, this.getDenominator());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("LINE 90 EXECUTED WHICH MEANS SOMETHING IS WRONG");
            return new Rational(this.getNumerator(), this.getDenominator());
        }

    }

    public Rational subtract(Rational other)
    {
        return add(new Rational(-other.numerator, other.denominator));
    }

    public Rational divide(Rational other)
    {
        return multiply(other.reciprocalNumber());
    }

    public Rational multiply(Rational other)
    {
        int newNumerator = this.getNumerator() * other.getNumerator();
        int newDenominator = this.getDenominator() * other.getDenominator();
        return new Rational(newNumerator, newDenominator);
    }

    public int getNumerator()
    {
        return this.numerator;
    }

    public void setNumerator(int numerator)
    {
        this.numerator = numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator()
    {
        return this.denominator;
    }

    public void setDenominator(int denominator)
    {
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String answer;

        if(denominator == 1)
        {
            answer = numerator + "";
        }
        else
        {
            answer = numerator + "/" + denominator;
        }
        return answer;
    }

}
```

The only other class is literally just a driver class to test values.

Comment: You have to override it so that you can have a custom output message.

Comment: Ya i get that. But the thing is you can just call your super with a string arg. Such as super("you cannot divide by zero");

Comment: Well, you are doing some extra logic in your `getMessage` method

Comment: So call `super(message)` in your constructor, and there is no need to override the `getMessage()` method.

Comment: Like I understand why i need to override getMessage to use getMessage. But maybe my real problem is with how i call that exception. Say i had a class that had parameters of a fraction. I want to check if the denominator of that fraction is 0. How would i do that, and print out my getMessage method using what i have now?

Comment: Haha @Amir that's what i want to do but my teacher says explicitly to override getMessage!

Answer (score 0):

Example of defining custom runtime exception:

```
public static int divide(x,y) {
  double result;
  if (y==0) {
     throw new CustomException("Cannot divide by 0");
  }
  else {
     result = x/y;
  }
     return result;
}

public class CustomException extends RuntimeException {
   public CustomException (String errorMsg) {
   super(errorMsg);
}
```

Comment: Ooops! You check x for 0, then divide by y?

Comment: oooops, that's what happens when you run after reputation points :P. tnx for pointing it out (*feeling a bit awkward now*)